# Gate pulse distorted on connecting to MOSFET Gate

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, mosfet-driver, gate-driving, powermosfet

I have a circuit consisting of multiple power MOSFETs (IRFP460), which need to be switched in a particular sequence. I am using an FPGA to generate the gate pulses (15 V), and connecting that to the gate via optocoupler 6n137.  Before connecting to the MOSFETs, the FPGA outputs are perfect squares. However, on connecting to the gate of the MOSFETs, the shape of the gate voltage gets completely distorted. As a result, the circuit is not working. What is happening here?

Comment: A MOSFET gate is a capacitor. Is your driver capable of driving a large capacitive load? The IRFP460's input capacitance is 4.2 nF.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us the relevant part of your schematic as well as some scope traces.

Comment: A schematic is required.

Comment: I'm not aware of any FPGA that outputs 15V pulses directly. And 6N137 does not drive a gate by itself, it needs a (n isolated?) power supply too. Much information is missing.

Answer (score 4):

A MOSFET gate is a capacitor. For power MOSFETs, this can be quite large; in the case of the [IRFP460](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91237/91237.pdf), it's 4.2 nF.

Most modern digital circuitry isn't designed to drive much current on its outputs. But if you want to charge a capacitive load quickly, you need to drive it with a pulse of fairly high current. The [6n137](https://www.vishay.com/docs/84732/6n137.pdf) has an open-drain output, meaning that its high-state drive current is determined entirely by its pull-up resistor, which you don't specify but can't provide more than 50 mA (by the absolute maximum rating of the device). 50 mA into a 4.2 nF capacitor will take 4.5 μs to charge up to 15 V.

This is why gate drivers exist. A gate driver is little more than a special-purpose power amplifier, taking a logic-level input and driving a high-current (and possibly higher-voltage) output to quickly charge or discharge the gate of a MOSFET or IGBT.

---

As an aside, you're also using that 6n137 at double its maximum output voltage. The datasheet lists an absolute maximum of 7 V, so if you're using 15 V I'm surprised it's not dead.

Answer (score 2):

There must be a low impedance gate drive circuit  between the opto-coupler and the FET gate.

The high gate capacitance requires fast high current edges to cleanly switch the gate.

Be certain that the high level voltage is higher than the Miller plateau voltage but not higher than the gate maximum, to obtain a low drain-source on resistance.

Comment: I'm sure "ez errs" is a typo, but I can't figure out of what.

Comment: Auto- correct or auto-incorrect @Hearth

Comment: "Miller plateau voltage", I've never heard that expression before but think I know exactly what you mean (and searching this site for that phrase I see 64 hits).  An interesting way to think/see if your gate drive voltage is sufficient and you are actually turning the thing on

Comment: @DanielChisholm Just to clarify, the Miller plateau is the point in the gate charge curve where the gate-to-drain capacitance is being charged as the drain voltage falls. The gate voltage is approximately (key word: approximately. the slope is related to the FET's transconductance.) constant during this, hence the term plateau. Once the drain voltage reaches its minimum (i.e. the device is pretty much fully on), the gate voltage starts to rise again.